# AWS S3 Video Streaming

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming

I have uploaded several videos (mp4) to my AWS S3 container. When I play mp4s that are relatively small (i.e. under 100mb) - everything works fine with the code below, BUT when I attempt to play an mp4 that is upwards of 600mb or higher, I just get the spinning loading animation - with the exact same code. I am using an open source html 5 video player (not using Cloudfront) and I set the AWS permissions correctly to "everyone" and set the META type to "audio/mpeg". Any clue to why the larger files are not playing?

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="720" height="460" poster="https://s3.amazonaws.com/filmpax/posters/Joe-Dirt.jpg" data-setup="{}"> 

<source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/filmpax/movies/Joe-Dirt.mp4" type='video/mp4' />

</video>
```

Comment: I changed  META type to "video/mp4" - still no luck but the smaller files still play as desired?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: No solution, sorry